# Unknown Format error after submitting a Rails form via jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to submit a form ('#new_comment')in my Rails app by clicking a button using jQuery with the following code:

```
 $('body').on('click', '#quick_reply_wait_list > li', function(event) {
    $('#comment_content').val( event.currentTarget.innerText );
    $('#new_comment').submit();
 });
```

The form is submitted but Rails raises a 406 - Unknown Format Error. My controller is set to respond_to JS, the form is set to `remote: true`, the params are OK, and it works just fine if I use the original submit form button.

Following the advice of a Stack Overflow post I've tried submitting the form instead with:

```
 $('#new_comment').trigger('submit.rails');
```

I've got the same results. Any help?

Comment: if all you want to do is to submit your form via AJAX, then adding 'remote: true' on the form is sufficient. You don't need to add another jQuery listener to handle this.

Comment: I know, but in this case I'm not writing a separate Ajax call, I'm simply trying to bind an isolated HTML element to a click event that triggers the submission of a form. It'd be essentially like having two submit buttons for the same form in different sections of the view. I'm assuming there's probably no need to write an Ajax call for that element and simply trigger the submit button of the form kind of 'remotely' via other element.

Comment: it might help if you can show the form and the log